# Html5 / Javascript - Button Click Eventhandler stops working

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am new to html5 and am trying to make a simple game where you have to guess a number between 0 and 99.

I have gotten it to work but at some point (possibly when I started adding css?) the button stops working when you click on it. Pressing the enter key still works fine though.

Any ideas why the click event handler stops working and how to fix it?

Here is the code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Guessing Game</title>
<body>  
<p id="Message">I am thinking of a number between 0 and 99.</p>
<input id="Guess" type="text" placeholder="Enter your guess here." autofocus>   

<button id="GuessClick" type=button>enter</button>  

<script type="text/javascript">         
        var RandomNumber = 0;
        var NumberGuessed = 0;
        var NumberOfGuesses = 0;

        var Message = document.querySelector("#Message");
        var Guess = document.querySelector("#Guess");
        var GuessClick = document.querySelector("#GuessClick");

        RandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100); 

        GuessClick.style.cursor = "pointer";
        GuessClick.addEventListener("click", EnterGuess, false);
        window.addEventListener("keydown", EnterGuess, false);          

        function EnterGuess()
        {

            if(event.keyCode !== 13)
            {
                return;
            }

            NumberGuessed = parseInt(Guess.value);

            if (isNaN(NumberGuessed) === true || NumberGuessed < 0 || NumberGuessed > 99)
            {
                Message.innerHTML = "Please enter a number between 0 and 99 inclusive. " + "You have guessed " + NumberOfGuesses + " times.";   
                return;
            }

            if (NumberGuessed > RandomNumber)
            {
                NumberOfGuesses = NumberOfGuesses + 1;
                Message.innerHTML = "Lower,  you have guessed " + NumberOfGuesses + " times. Previous guess was " + NumberGuessed + ".";
                Guess.value = ""
            }   

            if (NumberGuessed < RandomNumber)
            {
                NumberOfGuesses = NumberOfGuesses + 1;
                Message.innerHTML = "Higher,  you have guessed " + NumberOfGuesses + " times. Previous guess was " + NumberGuessed + ".";
                Guess.value = ""
            }

            if (NumberGuessed === RandomNumber)                 
            {
                Message.innerHTML = "Correct! The mystery number was " + RandomNumber + ". It took you " + NumberOfGuesses + " guesses to get it! Enter another number to play again";
                NumberOfGuesses = 0;
                RandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
                Guess.value = ""
            }   
        }
</script>
<style>
#GuessClick
{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    cursor: pointer;

    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;    

    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #a3a3a3, #000);
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #a3a3a3, #000);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #a3a3a3, #000);

    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

#GuessClick:hover
{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #acc7a3, #506651);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #acc7a3, #506651);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #acc7a3, #506651);
}

#GuessClick:active
{
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #858565, #c5c9a9);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #858565, #c5c9a9);
background: linear-gradient(top, #858565, #c5c9a9);
}

</style>        
</body>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "TypeError: GuessClick is null". Seems the queryselector doesnt find the button.

Comment: And then "event is undefined". Try some debugger to fix it.

Comment: Define "doesn't work."  What *does* it do?  Is there an error on the JavaScript console?  When you debug this, what happens?  Is the click event handled?  Does the function get called?  Where/how does the function complete?  "It doesn't work" isn't a helpful problem description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The event.keyCode for a mouse click will fail your if statement and get returned out of the function, you need to adjust the if to check for enter key OR click

```
if((event.keyCode !== 13) && (event.keyCode !== 0))
  {
     return;
  }
```

[**JSfiiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/9aTS4/)